# Android; MapView, how can I set default location?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-2.2-froyo

Using the MapView in android, how can I set a default location, so that everytime I load up this application, it automatically centers/zooms location in on London?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Firstly, get the controller for the given map:

```
MapController myMapController = myMapView.getController();
```

and then call:

```
myMapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint())
```

This will set the center of the map on the given GeoPoint.

See docs for [MapView](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html) and [MapController](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

For new Google Maps API you need to do this:

```
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this::setUpMaps);
```

And inside `setUpMaps(GoogleMap googleMap)` you should move camera to your default location:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, zoom));
```